# rev_append vs (append or @)

Tags: functional-programming, time-complexity, ocaml

If we have two lists `l1` and `l2` and we want to concatenate them we can use `@` or `append` which is in `O(n1)` where `n1` is the length of `l1`. Or we can use `rev_append` which is according to the doc:

```
equivalent to List.rev l1 @ l2, but rev_append is tail-recursive and more efficient.
```

So is `rev_append` more efficient than `@` or is it more efficient than `List.rev + @`? And is it better to use it instead of `@` and `append` when we don't care about the order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml lists are immutable. The second list doesn't need to be changed, but the first list has to be copied so the copy can point to the second list. Hence you're going to have to traverse the first list somehow. Nothing you can do will change the big-O time complexity of the append.

Since you can only add new elements at the beginning of a list, you need to traverse the first list in reverse order if you want the result to preserve the order of the first list.

The most obvious way to do this is to call recursively until you're at the end of the first list, then do the prefixing as you return from each recursive call. However this isn't tail-recursive. I.e., it will consume stack space proportional to the length of the first list. When the first list is long, you can run out of stack space (aka stack overflow).

This is the way that `@` works. It takes time and stack space proportional to the length of the first list.

Another idea is to give up on maintaining the order of the first list. If you prefix the first list in reverse order, you can can easily make the operation tail recursive. That's the purpose of `List.rev_append`. It takes constant stack space.

If you want to maintain the original list orders, but also use constant stack space you can reverse the first list (with `List.rev`), then use `List.rev_append`.

Plain `List.rev_append` is faster than `@` because it doesn't have to make internal function calls--it can just be a loop. It's also obviously faster than `List.rev` plus `List.rev_append`.

In summary if you don't care about the final order, then `List.rev_append` is faster than `@`, yes. Also it won't overflow the stack. It's not going to be a gigantic amount faster because the time complexity is basically the same.